# read-only filesystem, no X11 when booting lubuntu 17.10 from battery

Tags: boot, lubuntu, laptop, battery, 17.10

I upgraded my "acer aspire e13" laptop to lubuntu 17.10 (from 16.04, via 17.04) a few days ago and experience the following:

- when booting with power cable plugged in, everything works.
- whithout power cable, it doesn't start X11.  Instead I can log in at the console. After logging in I get two or three messages about upgrade demon not being able to write a temporary file because the disk is mounted read only.

The battery is certainly fine, I can work for hours on it.

I don't even know where to start looking.

UPDATE - by request of Katu, [here is the output of dmesg](http://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/rubey/fail.dmesg).  I have still no clue.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in a live session?

Comment: If you mean: boot, unplug, reboot, the answer is yes.

Comment: I mean with an USB drive or CD.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have one.  I could possibly check next week.  Is there any way to find out what specifically is going wrong?  I guess no logfiles are being written due to the fs being read-only, right?

Comment: Could be hardware related.

Comment: Let me stress that 16.04 worked without any problems.

Comment: @MartinRubey, Do you have any proprietary driver (Graphics, Wireless...etc) in use for 17.10?

Comment: At least lxde menu > Preferences > Additional Drivers says that I don't.  Is there a console way to check?

Comment: Do you have any power management apps such as TLP installed?

Comment: I have laptop-mode-tools installed (which I also had on 16.04).

Comment: Check the file `/etc/fstab`. Normally when a disk failure occurs, it will be remounted as read only. This is set in that file. I would start with the output of `dmesg` to detect errors. It would be useful to add the output to your question.

Comment: A live system run from USB or DVD would indeed be a quick and simple way to narrow down the possible sources of the issue.

Comment: Do you have the previous  stable version of kernel (which you used earlier), if yes, boot that from Grub menu at startup and check if the problem still exists.

Comment: I tried a few kernels (including old ones), but without success.  I admit that I cannot tell whether the kernel I had in 16.04 was among them.

Comment: Here are bug reports on Launchpad about this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1725458
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/laptop-mode-tools/+bug/1726930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Kubuntu 17.04 to Kubuntu 17.10. `laptop-mode-tools` was installed. Uninstalling it (`apt remove laptop-mode-tools --purge`) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have gathered in my testing of this error on my machine is that the bios battery is failing, or in my case the battery is failing period.. I have lost 1/2 the cells.

A different error but related to a RO filesystem lead me to believe this is the case. I can't find that link as I was booted into a live instance. Pretty simple test. Plugged in. Booted x11. Didn't plug in. No x for you.